# Traceroute provides a route that takes longer than 100 hops

Tags: latency, networking

I have a server that I configured using zoneedit. Upon running "traceroute" on it I notice that it takes more than 100 hops.

- How do I lower the number of hops?
- Is this really that bad or am I too paranoid?
- Would the nameserver play a role in the number of hops.

Answer (score 3):

Over 100 hops indicates that there is a problem somewhere, or that you don't have access to a segment of the path.

Do you get `* * *` or repeated IP addresses?
Try with the `-m` option to limit the number of hops to a number < 100

```
  traceroute -m 90 mydomain.tld
```

thus you should get at least some indications about what is going wrong.

Comment: It is all '* * *'. I had tried with default of 30 and later increased it to 100. Would the nameserver of the server make a difference? We currently use zoneedit and if I wanted to make our server easily findable to lower the latency what would I need to do?

Comment: It seems the *hops* you see are actually blanks `* * *` because there is a firewall or router that prevents the *trace* to go further. Not a real problem. I don't think the DNS is related to that - DNS is used at first to get the IP of the server / domain you want. You shouldn't worry much.

Comment: ring0: Correct, DNS is not the issue here. There is a firewall or a router blocking icmp requests along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [tcptraceroute](http://michael.toren.net/code/tcptraceroute/) (or similar) with a destination port of 80 (or any other port you might think be open on the remote server) and see how that goes.

Like ring0 said above, this is not a DNS issue - it's a router or a firewall "out there" who blocks standard traceroute packets (icmp).